# How can I pause for 100+ milliseconds in a linux driver module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, delay, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel driver for a device that produces regular amounts of data for reading periodically.  The user space program is ideally suited to making this a blocking driver.

**What methods are available for pausing anywhere from 4 to 100ms in a driver (i.e. doing the "*block*")**?  In user space I'd do something akin to:

```
tv.tv_sec  = microsecond_delay / 1000000ul;
tv.tv_usec = microsecond_delay % 1000000ul;
(void)select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, & tv);
```

or

```
gettimeofday(tv,NULL);
```

and compare the structures.

[Edit - my own answer]

I will be using the following code in my driver:

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
...
schedule_timeout(file->private_data->my_driver_struct.read_pause_jiffies);
```

Voila! I shall now test ...

Comment: Actually, not what I'm looking for: I want to sleep a specified time, not create an asynchronous timer event.

Comment: Found it: `extern signed long schedule_timeout(signed long timeout);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sleep in the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994603/how-to-sleep-in-the-linux-kernel)

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功 Check the date.  I asked first.

Comment: hi, current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newbie Google keywords on the title.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
#include <linux/delay.h>

...
msleep(100);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using schedule_timeout does NOT sleep for a specified time but for a minimum specified time. If you really want to **block** for a specified time, you will have to use locks. Sleeping will only guarantee you a minimum time - this may not matter to you depending on much granularity you need.
But a better driver would sleep until the reader asked for more data in any case.

Comment: Okay ... locks, will look it up.  But the granularity is going to be, what? +- 10msec? (BTW: your answer is more comment material than answer)

Comment: ... and a pointer to something regarding my question and your suggestion of using locks would be much appreciated.  Or, better (much better :)), an answer with three or four lines of relevant API code!